# Flow chart and a polyline

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I would like to improve the following code : my problem is explained in the screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Source: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/


% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=green!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text badly centered, node distance=2.5cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text centered, node distance=2.5cm, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{loop} = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text centered, node distance=2.5cm, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=2.5cm,
    text width=6.5em, text centered, minimum height=2em]


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [cloud] (input) {$(n ; x) \in N \times R$};
    \node [block, below of=input] (affect1) {$u \leftarrow x$}; 
    \node [loop, below of=affect1] (whileinit) {$i \leftarrow 1$};
    \node [decision, below of=whileinit] (whiletest) {$i \leq n$}; 
    \node [block, below of=whiletest] (affect2) {$u \leftarrow A_1(u)$};
    \node [loop, left of=affect2] (whilenext) {$i \leftarrow i + 1$};
    \node [cloud, below of=affect2] (output) {$u$};

    \path[line] (input) -- (affect1);
    \path[line] (affect1) -- (whileinit);
    \path[line] (whileinit) -- (whiletest);
    \path[line] (whiletest) -- node {oui} (affect2);
    \path[line] (affect2) -- (whilenext);
    \path[line] (whilenext) |- (whiletest);
    \path[line] (whiletest.east) -| node {non} ($(whiletest)!.7!(output.east)$) -| (output.north);%  (output);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems can be solved by

1. loading and using the `positioning` library and
2. changing the `non` path.

The first point means that e.g. `below of=` needs to go to `below=<distance> of`. The distance can be omitted in which case the `node distance` values get used. As for the second point, I used

```
\path[line] (whiletest.east) -- ++ (2cm,0) node[right] {non} |-
    ([yshift=-5mm]affect2.south) -- (output.north);
```

where `2cm` controls the distance, and you may adjust this to your likings. In addition I replaced `\tikzstyle` by the corresponding `\tikzset` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,positioning}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Source: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/


% Define block styles
\tikzset{decision/.style={diamond, draw, fill=green!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text badly centered, node distance=2.5cm, inner sep=0pt},
block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text centered, node distance=2.5cm, rounded corners, minimum height=2em},
loop/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text centered, node distance=2.5cm, rounded corners, minimum height=2em},
line/.style={draw, -latex'},
cloud/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=2.5cm,
    text width=6.5em, text centered, minimum height=2em}}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm and 0.8cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [cloud] (input) {$(n ; x) \in N \times R$};
    \node [block, below=of input] (affect1) {$u \leftarrow x$}; 
    \node [loop, below=of affect1] (whileinit) {$i \leftarrow 1$};
    \node [decision, below=of whileinit] (whiletest) {$i \leq n$}; 
    \node [block, below=of whiletest] (affect2) {$u \leftarrow A_1(u)$};
    \node [loop, left=of affect2] (whilenext) {$i \leftarrow i + 1$};
    \node [cloud, below=of affect2] (output) {$u$};

    \path[line] (input) -- (affect1);
    \path[line] (affect1) -- (whileinit);
    \path[line] (whileinit) -- (whiletest);
    \path[line] (whiletest) -- node {oui} (affect2);
    \path[line] (affect2) -- (whilenext);
    \path[line] (whilenext) |- (whiletest);
    \path[line] (whiletest.east) -- ++ (2cm,0) node[right] {non} |-
    ([yshift=-5mm]affect2.south) -- (output.north);%  (output);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should maybe add that `\tikzstyle` and the positioning mechanisms that do not use the `positioning` library are *really* *really* deprecated. They should definitely not be used in any answer in the year 2019.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. Is there a way to obtain the same flowchart without using old cars ? This is more curiosity than necessity because I have to go to sleep.

Comment: @projetmbc The above does not use "old cars", I think. You may make things a bit more automatic by using e.g. `chains` but this won't buy you much here. However, on the long run you will be way better off if you use `positioning` since its syntax is much more powerful.

Comment: Shame on me... I have read that do use `positioning`... Yesterday it was too late for me. Sorry fo the noise...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Source: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/


% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=green!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text badly centered, node distance=2.5cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text centered, node distance=2.5cm, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{loop} = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text centered, node distance=2.5cm, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=2.5cm,
    text width=6.5em, text centered, minimum height=2em]


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [cloud] (input) {$(n ; x) \in N \times R$};
    \node [block, below of=input] (affect1) {$u \leftarrow x$}; 
    \node [loop, below of=affect1] (whileinit) {$i \leftarrow 1$};
    \node [decision, below of=whileinit] (whiletest) {$i \leq n$}; 
    \node [block, below of=whiletest] (affect2) {$u \leftarrow A_1(u)$};
    \node [loop,left] at ($(affect2)+(-3,0)$) (whilenext) {$i \leftarrow i + 1$};
    \node [cloud, below of=affect2] (output) {$u$};

    \path[line] (input) -- (affect1);
    \path[line] (affect1) -- (whileinit);
    \path[line] (whileinit) -- (whiletest);
    \path[line] (whiletest) -- node {oui} (affect2);
    \path[line] (affect2) -- (whilenext);
    \path[line] (whilenext) |- (whiletest);
    \path[line] (whiletest.east) -| node {non} ($(whiletest)!.7!($(output.east)+(3,0)$)$) -| (output.north);%  (output);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I just used your code and improved the requested things by just adding `(-3,0)` or `(3,0)` to your given positions. I think this is something easy to learn and can give you much more flexibility than creating the code from scratch -in my way- and instead of introducing just this simple thing to you.

Comment: Interesting to see how to play with relative coordinates. Not so natural for me...

Comment: @projetmbc ... You was already using calc library, and I just wanted to add this answer to show you how to use it. Of course you may learn much more things, but with this one you already learn, you can do much things now. (Good choice your accepted answer and you can learn some more stuff there ... )